# Vertical-align image without absolute position

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have a slider with images, some of which are bigger than the viewport.

The top of the images aligns with the top of the viewport, so that the bottom part of the images is cut with overflow:hidden.

```
div.flex-viewport{
height:350px !important;
overflow:hidden !important;
}

div.flex-viewport img{
min-height:350px !important;
min-width:940px !important;
}
```

But I want the bottom of the images to be aligned with the bottom of the viewport, so that the top is cut.

Normally, I would use absolute positioning to achieve this, but that somehow renders the images invisible (in FlexSlider).

Vertical-align doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the height of the image with CSS

```
.classofimage {
 height: heightofslider;
}
```

Let the width be flexible. To put in the images, make sure the width of all images does not exceed the slider width. You can do this in photoshop.